# Some but not all Excel numbers show as a date

Tags: excel

I have a big .xls file. Some numbers show as a date.
31.08 shows as 31.aug
31.13 shows as 31.13 (that is what i want all columns to be)
When I reformat 31.aug to number it shows as 40768,00 
I have found no ways to convert 31.aug to 31.08 as a number. All I am able to do is to reformat 31.aug as d.mm and then it shows as 31.08 and when I try to reformat it from 31.08 to number it shows as 40768,00. No way to cheat Excel using different types of cell formats.

Comment: Changing the format to a number, then putting in 31.08 should keep it as a number of that value.

Comment: Isn't number the default format? Did you apply a date format to all the cells before entering your data?

Comment: @bdares: 'putting in' a 'big .xls file' is not always a good idea in a computerized era. @reforrer: you could reformat all cells to d.mm, then copy them, then do something like 'paste special' in the menu and then choose just the text.

Comment: If this file has for example 1000 rows that show as a date but need to be show as a number then it is impossible to change them manually within reasonable time.

Comment: That "paste special" trick doesn't seem to work either. The cell shows value of 31.08 but function bar shows it as 31.08.2011. So internally this 31.08 is 31.08.2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's your regional settings? There are some Regions where the short date is identified by dd.mm.yyyy. (Estonian, for instance). Maybe if you change the regional settings for US / UK and paste the data again it won't be changed.

Worked in a small test I did here. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Internally Excel stores Dates as integer. 1 is January 1. 1900. If you entered something that Excel interprets as a date then it will be converted into an integer. I think from this point on there is no way back.

There is an setting in Options on the tab "international" where you can define your decimal separator. If you set this to ".", then your Excel should accept 30.12 as decimal number and not as date.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, Excel interprets some of your data as a date instead of a number, which depends on your regional settings. To avoid this happening try Tiago's and stema's responses, they will work depending on your regional settings.

To repair your problem in a large file after it has happened without re-entering/re-importing your data, you can use something like

```
=DAY(B5)+MONTH(B5)/100
```

to convert a "date" back to a number. Excel will still display it as a date when you first enter this, but when you reformat it as "Number" now it will display the value you originally entered.

Since your column seems to contain a mix between correct numbers and dates, you need to add an if() construct to separate the two cases. If you haven't changed the display format yet (i.e. it still displays 31.Aug) you can use

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format";B7);1)="D";DAY(B7)+MONTH(B7)/100;B7)
```

which checks if the format is a "D"ate format. If you have already changed the format to Number, but know all your correct data is below 40000, you can use

```
=IF(B5>40000;DAY(B5)+MONTH(B5)/100;B5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, go to `Control Panel - Region and Language - Advanced Settings - Numbers - and change the Decimal Symbol from "," to "."`
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The data you are pasting, is it by any chance a pivot table.

For example, like you, I am copying a lot of data into a large spreadsheet. The data I am copying is from another sheet and it is a pivot table.

If I paste normally, half will show up as numbers, which they are in the source file and half will show up as dates, for no reason, which drives me insane.

If I Paste->Values however, they will all show up as numbers, and as I don't need the pivot functionality in the destination file this solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is format cell.

1-right click on the cell where you want to insert the number.

2-then click on Number and select 'General' from the number menu.

Hope this will help future people with the same issue.